# Enable VM Insights (in Azure) using Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring, azure-python-sdk

Is there a way to enable VM insights in azure using azure python sdk ?
Need to enable this so that the InsightMetrics/PerfMetrics are available in Log Analytics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can enable VM insights using Azure Python SDK.

1. Create a workspace using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-loganalytics/azure.mgmt.loganalytics.operations.workspacesoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-loganalytics-operations-workspacesoperations-begin-create-or-update
2. Enable OmsAgentForLinux, DependencyAgentLinux entensions on the required VM   using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2021_04_01.operations.virtualmachineextensionsoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-compute-v2021-04-01-operations-virtualmachineextensionsoperations-begin-create-or-update
3. Install VM insights solution on the Workspace using azure deployments.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/vminsights-configure-workspace?tabs=CLI#add-vminsights-solution-to-workspace
   This has the process for VM insights solution using cli. The same can done using python sdk using deployments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2019_05_01.operations.deploymentsoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-resource-resources-v2019-05-01-operations-deploymentsoperations-begin-create-or-update
   We need to deploy the VM insights solution to our workspace.